# Question about showing $L^1$ is complete.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I have a proof of $L^1$ being complete (no need to read all of it since it is the traditional proof):

> Let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a Cauchy sequence in $L^1(X)$. It is
>   sufficient to find a convergent subsequence. By definition, for all
>   $k>0$, there is some $N_k$ such that $||f_n-f_m||<2^{-k}$ for all
>   $n,m\geq N_k$. Set $g_k:=f_{N_k}$. Then $||g_k-g_{k+1}||\leq2^{-k}$
>   as we can pick $N_{k+1}> N_k$.
>
> Now, set $h_1(x)=|g_1(x)|$ and 
>   $$h_{n+1}(x)=|g_1(x)|+\sum_{k=1}^{n}|g_{k+1}(x)-g_k(x)|$$ Then
>   $\{h_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is nonnegative and nondecreasing. We also have by
>   the linearity of the integral $$\int h_n=||{g_1}||+\sum_{k=1}^n||{g_{k+1}-g_k}||\leq ||{g_1}||+\sum_{k=1}^n{2^{-k}}\leq||{g_1}||+1$$ Thus $\lim \int h_n\leq ||{g_1}||+1$. Applying the monotone convergence theorem to
>   $\{h_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ gives us that the limit
>   $$|g_1(x)|+\sum_{n=1}^\infty |g_{n+1}(x)-g_n(x)|$$ is integrable since
>   it is a non-negative function that has a finite integral. This also
>   implies that it is finite a.e. Writing 
>   $$g_n(x)=g(x)+\sum_{k=1}^n[g_{k+1}(x)-g_k(x)]$$ gives us that
>   $f(x)=\lim g_n(x)$ exists (it is the sum of an absolutely convergent
>   series) for a.e $x$ (so $f\in L^1$). Finally, to show convergence in the $L^1$-norm,
>   we note that $$|f(x)-g_n(x)|\leq\left\lvert\sum_{k=n}^\infty [g_{k+1}(x)-g_k(x)]\right\rvert\leq \sum_{k=n}^\infty |g_{k+1}(x)-g_k(x)|$$ so then we can apply the monotone convergence
>   theorem to the partial sums we get $$||{f(x)-g_n(x)}||\leq \sum_{k=n}^\infty ||{g_{k+1}(x)-g_k(x)}||\leq 2^{1-n}$$ and thus $f$
>   is the desired limit.

I have a few questions:

1. Is the reason why we only need to show that $\lim g_n(x)$ exists for a.e. $x$ because the $L^1$ space does not care about null sets? It seems to me that $f$ does not equal $\lim g_n(x)$ on all $x$ because $\lim g_n(x)$ could take on values of infinity, which is not in $\mathbb{R}$ (but $f$ maps to $\mathbb{R}$). Would $f$ technically be a function that agrees with $\lim g_n(x)$ pointwise everywhere except when $\lim g_n(x)=\infty$ (taking any value in $\mathbb{R}$ on those points)? If $f$ is not precisely $\lim g_n(x)$, does that break the last part of the proof?
2. Building off of that idea, if I had a sequence of functions $f_n\rightarrow f$ for a.e. $x$, would I be able to say $f = \liminf f_n$ even if the convergence is not strictly pointwise? I guess in general, what does "$\leq$" mean in $L^1$?

Comment: $L^1$ doesn't distinguish functions that agree a.e. at all, indeed from the point of view of metric spaces this distinction simply doesn't exist at all. Accordingly, when picking a particular representative, you can define $f$ on the problematic null set to be whatever you want. I don't really understand your second question.

Comment: @Ian I guess I am wondering what it means when one writes $f\leq g$ in $L^1$, for example. I would assume that is equivalent to $f\leq g$ a.e.? Also, just to clarify, if I have $f_n\rightarrow f$, that would mean that $\lim f_n=f$ a.e., right?